# Property of List of T object

Tags: vb.net, list, visual-studio-2012, types, member

In Visual Basic.net, If I have a List of T, where the Type is an object that always has a .Name property, how I can write a function that returns the .Name value?

Here is my code:

```
Public Function GetListOfListItemNames(Of T)(ListOfItems As List(Of T)) As List(Of String)
    Dim ListToReturn As New List(Of String)
    For x = 0 To ListOfItems.Count - 1
        ListToReturn.Add(ListOfItems.Item(x).Name)
    Next
    Return ListToReturn
End Function
```

I am getting the following error:

> Name' is not a member of 'T'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a constraint on your generic method. Specifically, your `GetListOfListItemNames(Of T)` should be defined as `GetListOfListItemNames(Of T As BaseType)` where `BaseType` is the type that you expect to be contained in the list.

I'm not familiar with VB.Net to any great extent, so my syntax may be incorrect. But the need for a generic constraint is not:

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx for specifics.